# Catching errors within async await

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
exports.signup = async(req, res) => {
  console.log('signup');
  const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
  });

  try {
    if (await user.save()) {
        if (isNonEmptyArray(req.body.roles)) {
            // How do I catch this error? can be a role error or db error
            const roles = await Role.find({name: { $in: req.body.roles }}).exec()
            user.roles = roles.map(role => role._id);
            if (await user.save()) {
              success(res, 'Registered!');
            }
        } else {
            // How do I catch this error? can be a role error or a db error
            const role = await Role.findOne({name: 'user'}).exec();
            user.roles = [role._id];
            if (await user.save()) {
              success(res, 'Registered!');
            }
        }
    }
  } catch(error) {
    fail(res, {message: 'Database internal error occured.'});
  }
};
```

Is it correct that the catch will trigger for all errors in the block including calls to `await Role.find({name: { $in: req.body.roles }}).exec()`? How would I catch this error independently? Do I need to add a `try` and `catch` within the `try` and `catch` statement?

Comment: Did you just try to `throw` an exception in there and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

like you said you can use another try-catch block to distinguish which error are you catching.

```
try {
   const role = await Role.findOne({name: 'user'}).exec();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Another idea might be to use the promises and catch the error in each .catch segment, for example

```
var query = Role.findOne({name: 'user'});
query.exec().then(function () {
    // handle success
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle error
});
```

anyway there are some important to feature to keep in mind when using async/await and try-catch block, I'll put here the conclusion of an article and the link to it if you are interested:

conclusion:

We can use try...catch for synchronous code.

We can use try...catch (in combination with async functions) and the .catch() approaches to handle errors for asynchronous code.

When returning a promise within a try block, make sure to await it if you want the try...catch block to catch the error.

Be aware when wrapping errors and rethrowing, that you lose the stack trace with the origin of the error.

font: https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a

Comment: It's not "another idea", it's exactly the same thing using different sytanx.

Comment: You are right, I re-red the mongoose documentation and the .exec return a promise (unlike the simple query ) so it is the same, the difference in sintax might be useful for the reason said in the citated article